# GnuWin32 make returns strange error on square braket

Tags: windows, cmd, makefile, gnuwin32

I am trying to compile a project on Windows 7 with GNUWin32 make. I am running make from the folder where Makefile sits, but I receive the following error:

```
[ ! -d libmf ] && mkdir -p libmf
"[" is not recognised  as internal or external command, operable program or batch file
```

I guess that for some reason cmd interpreter does not parse square bracket, but this notation is described in manuals, and the makefile comes from the vendor and supposed to be correct. I tried 'make' with different targets, the text in erroneous line changes (target defines the macro there), but the error is the same.
The place in makefile that causes this looks like this:

```
libmf$(LIBSUFFIX):
                [ ! -d $@ ] && mkdir -p $@
```

Comment: `[ ! -d libmf ]` is bash syntax, this cannot work unless you invoke make in a bash shell like that provided by Cygwin or Msys2.

Comment: You are right, thanks. With cygwin's make it works ok!

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. Should have used cygwin instead of gnuwin32, as gnuwin32 does not contain all the required commands. A curious detail: cygwin actually has '[.exe' program to emulate bash bracket parsing.